# JSON format issue?

Tags: json

I am debugging a perl module that generates JSON and what I know about JSON you could probably fit in a thimble. The JSON is here.....

```
xvarStore_json = {
     identifier: 'name',
     label: 'name',
     items: [
          {name: "CR_Local_ID"} ,
          {name: "CR_Patient_ID"} ,
          {name: "test("MEDICARE PART B","xvar:X_Primary_Payer","1","1")"} 
            ]
};
```

The error I am getting in Firebug is ..

```
missing } after property list
    {name: "test("MEDICARE PART B","xvar:X_Primary_Payer","1","1")"}
```

I would be happy to spend the time learning JSON if this weren't an urgent fix. Does anyone have an idea as to what's going wrong?

Janie

Comment: What you have there is not JSON.  Review Matt's link for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I agree @matt-ball in his answer, I don't think that's really the issue here.  The problem is this line:

```
{name: "test("MEDICARE PART B","xvar:X_Primary_Payer","1","1")"}
```

You need to escape your quotes inside the actual value:

```
{name: "test(\"MEDICARE PART B\",\"xvar:X_Primary_Payer\",\"1\",\"1\")"}
```

Comment: You're right, I took a second look at the problem and I agree with your answer.

Comment: AWESOME Grrovetrain! Works like a champ!

Answer (score 1):

That's not [JSON](http://json.org/); it is a [JavaScript object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Object_Literals). There is a very important difference.

The syntax highlighting gives away the problem: you're trying to use double quotes inside of a string that's delimited by double-quotes, so the string ends early. Just use single quotes to delimit the string instead.

```
{name: 'test("MEDICARE PART B","xvar:X_Primary_Payer","1","1")'}
```

And just to make it perfectly clear, [there's no such thing as a "JSON object."](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0):

Issue withe the unterminated quotes:

Replace with  {name: "test("MEDICARE PART B","xvar:X_Primary_Payer","1","1")"} with

```
{name: "test('MEDICARE PART B','xvar:X_Primary_Payer','1','1')"}
```

Your JSON object should look like:

```
xvarStore_json = {
         identifier: 'name',
         label: 'name',
         items: [
              {name: "CR_Local_ID"} ,
              {name: "CR_Patient_ID"} ,
              {name: "test('MEDICARE PART B','xvar:X_Primary_Payer','1','1')"}   
                ]
    };
```